# Error in Dataset$text : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Tags: r

I'm trying to perform a sentiment analysis of Tweeter..But at one stage I`ve got

> "Error in Dataset$text : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable"
>   :

```
Dataset <- stack    
Dataset$text <- as.factor(Dataset$text) 
scores <- score.sentiment(Dataset$text, pos.words, neg.words, .progress='text')
write.csv(scores, file=paste(searchterm, '_scores.csv'), row.names=TRUE)
```

Comment: Please check the `str(Dataset)` I would guess that it would be a `matrix`

Comment: If an object named `Dataset` existed before that assignment of `stack` to that name  , it got wiped out, since `stack` is an R function. So you then tried to apply teh subsetting function "$" to a function and got that error.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is assigning a function to the variable 'Dataset'.

If you type

```
?stack
```

in the console you could see what the function does.

For doing your analysis you need data.

The error message means that a function (which is of type closure) is not subsetable.

The dollar sign could be used to subset dataframes.

Read the documentation about dataframes.

```
?data.frame
```

First thing you should do is loading the data into your R  environment and assign the data to the variable 'Dataset' and not a function.

Maybe you could tell us what kind of data it is or whether the dataset is available on the net...

If so one could help you much more.

Or if you've already loaded the dataset and you want to stack the dataset and assign it to ne new variable 'Datset'  try:

```
Dataset <- stack(x)
```

where you have to replace x by the name of the dataset.

`stack` is a function which needs to be fed with a dataframe or list (documentation)